# Convert SQL query that use ManyToMany relationship to JPQL query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to convert the following SQL query into JPQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM movie m INNER JOIN movie_genre mg ON m.id = mg.movie_id
WHERE mg.genre_id = (SELECT mg2.genre_id FROM movie_genre mg2 WHERE mg2.movie_id = ?1 AND mg2.movie_id <> mg.movie_id AND mg.genre_id = mg2.genre_id)
GROUP BY mg.movie_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

The problem is that i don't have a model class to represent `movie_genre`  table because it's auto generated table from `ManyToMany` relationship.

so is there any way to convert that query into `JPQL`

In the moment I'm using a native query instead:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM movie m INNER JOIN movie_genre mg ON m.id = mg.movie_id " +
            "WHERE mg.genre_id = (SELECT mg2.genre_id FROM movie_genre mg2 WHERE mg2.movie_id = ?1 AND mg2.movie_id <> mg.movie_id AND mg.genre_id = mg2.genre_id) " +
            "GROUP BY mg.movie_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC", nativeQuery = true)
Page<Movie> findRelatedMoviesToAMovieById(@Param("id") int id, Pageable pageable);
```

Edit :
here's the models:
**Movie**

```
@Entity
public class Movie extends DateAudit  {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
     @JoinTable(name = "movie_genre",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id")
    )
    private List<Genre> genres = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Genre**

```
@Entity
public class Genre {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genres", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: Does the `movie_genre` table contains other attributes beside mapping ?

Comment: @ShafinMahmud Non only `id_movie` and `id_genre`

Comment: Do you have bidirectional relation mapping? `Movie` contains `genreList` and `Genre` contains `movieList` ? It would be nice if you mention your entity mapping.

Comment: @ShafinMahmud yes i have a bi-directional relation. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the SQL query you provided, I re-thought your requirement and translated that to a JPQL. So far what I understood you were *finding related movies to a movie having common genres*. If this is correct, you can achieve this by

```
SELECT m FROM Movie m JOIN m.genres mg 
WHERE mg.id IN 
         (SELECT g.id FROM Genre g JOIN g.movies gm WHERE gm.id = :movieId) 
AND m.id <> :movieId 
GROUP BY m ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

This will generate the SQL as below

```
 select distinct movie0_.id as id1_1_, movie0_.name as name2_1_ 
 from movie movie0_ inner join movie_genre genres1_ on movie0_.id=genres1_.movie_id inner join genre genre2_ on genres1_.genre_id=genre2_.id 
 where (genre2_.id in 
            (select genre3_.id from genre genre3_ inner join movie_genre movies4_ on genre3_.id=movies4_.genre_id inner join movie movie5_
             on  movies4_.movie_id=movie5_.id where movie5_.id=?)) 
 and movie0_.id <> ? 
 group by movie0_.id order by count(*) desc
```

### Querying Collection Association in JPQL

When you are using JPQL, you are in the Object Relationship world. So when you are querying for an association that is a collection, you access them through that collection field. And when it is a `ManyToMany` association, so you are not having a join table that does have a mapped entity, you need to Join with the collection field. And JPA vendor automatically translates that to join with the join table.

Like if you are querying *movies of certain genres*, this will go

```
 SELECT m FROM Movie m JOIN m.genres mg WHERE mg.id = :genreId
```

### Performance Concern

As you notice in the generated SQL, there are many levels of join to fetch and filter the data. This leads to a performance bottleneck. To overcome this, you can have entity for the `movie_genre` table.

This scenario is fairly discussed here

[The best way to map a many-to-many association with extra columns when using JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a model movie_genre in order to write a JPQL statement.  Hibernate knows about it implicitly when doing a JPQL statement.

Example:

```
SELECT m from Movie m left join m.genres g where g.name = 'Action'
```

The bidirectional   "m.genres g" works with all bidirectional JPQL statements, including many-to-many where the association model is implicit and not actually present.

Example Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MOVIE")
public class Movie {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column
private String name;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "movie_genre",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "genre_id")}
)
private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public Set<Genre> getGenres() {
    return genres;
}

public void setGenres(Set<Genre> genres) {
    this.genres = genres;
}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "GENRE")
public class Genre {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column
private String name;


@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genres", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<Movie> getMovies() {
    return movies;
}

public void setMovies(Set<Movie> movies) {
    this.movies = movies;
}
}
```

Working JPQL Example

```
    @PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

@Test
@Transactional
public void test() {
    Set<Movie> actionMovies = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Movie> dramaMovies = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Genre> dramaGenres = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Genre> actionGenres = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Genre> generes = new HashSet<>();

    Movie actionMovie = new Movie();
    actionMovie.setName("Batman");
    actionMovies.add(actionMovie);

    Movie dramaMovie = new Movie();
    dramaMovie.setName("Forest Gump");
    dramaMovies.add(dramaMovie);

    Genre actionGenre = new Genre();
    actionGenre.setName("Action");
    generes.add(actionGenre);
    actionGenres.add(actionGenre);

    Genre dramaGenre = new Genre();
    dramaGenre.setName("Drama");
    generes.add(dramaGenre);
    dramaGenres.add(dramaGenre);

    //Bidirectional sets
    actionGenre.setMovies(actionMovies);
    dramaGenre.setMovies(dramaMovies);
    actionMovie.setGenres(actionGenres);
    dramaMovie.setGenres(dramaGenres);

    genreRepository.saveAll(generes);

    //Example JPQL join through not present association model.
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT m from Movie m left join m.genres g where g.name = 'Action'");
    List<Movie> resultList = query.getResultList();
    assertEquals("Batman",resultList.get(0).getName());


}
```